# C'è qualche differenza tra "spaventevole" e "spaventoso"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Il suo nome per intero ha un suono musicale e magico, alle mie orecchie infantili, Maria Guadalupe Juana Isabel.
>   Musicale quanto il cognome peruviano della madre, Barrinechea de Winder, e magico quanto l'enigmatica figura – lei, ritratta di tre quarti – che arreda il salotto dei miei genitori: una donna dall'espressione severa, vestita di scuro e adorna solo di un medaglione d'oro e di un nastro di velluto al collo; dalle maniche, tagliate sotto il gomito, sporgono sbuffi di merletto bianco, a trama fitta; in una mano regge un libro; sull'altro braccio, invece, ha un pappagallo verde e rosso, con qualche piuma gialla sulla testa e un becco affilato e ricurvo, quasi una grossa virgola, e un occhio vitreo e ostile; almeno così sembra a me bambina, che non capisco perché il pittore abbia voluto ritrarre mia nonna con quella bestia **spaventevole** placidamente appollaiata sul braccio.

Il vocabolo "spaventevole" in questo brano ha attirato la mia attenzione perché non lo conoscevo. Ho letto la sua definizione nel vocabolario Treccani, ma non riesco a capire se c'è qualche differenza con "spaventoso", che mi è più familiare. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gli aggettivi spaventevole e spaventoso si possono considerare sinonimi in quasi tutte le circostanze, però il primo è meno usato, quindi nel linguaggio comune e nella comunicazione diretta è meglio usare il secondo.
Ci si può aspettare che un titolo di giornale contenga la frase "spaventoso incidente", ma non "spaventevole incidente".
Per la stessa ragione l'aggettivo spaventevole si presta meglio a sottolineare la particolarità di una certa situazione, o a rendere una frase più ricercata.

L'aggettivo spaventoso è più pratico da usare anche dal punto di vista fonetico, questa può essere una delle ragioni per cui è preferito.

Comment: Interessante l'osservazione sulla maggior “praticità fonetica”. Come mai consideri risparmiare una sillaba tanto vantaggioso? Peraltro, in questo periodo storico, sembra che la gente preferisca eccedere in sillabe: “tematica” (usato al posto di “tema”), “problematica” (“problema”), “similare” (“simile”), “quantitativo” (“quantità”) e così via.

Comment: @DaG Non è solo la sillaba in più, anche la sequenza di vocali e-o-e contribuisce alla poca praticità; comunque ammetto che questa è una valutazione soggettiva poco scientifica. Ad ogni modo è un dato di fatto, suffragato anche da una verifica su Ngram Viewer, che l'uso di spaventoso è quattro volte più frequente ai giorni nostri.

Comment: Sì, non avevo da ridire sulla minor frequenza di “spaventevole”; era solo che trovavo appunto un po' soggettiva la considerazione, diciamo, estetica.

Comment: @DaG in effetti: _uso_ → _utilizzo_ → _utilizzazione_ (tanti anni fa ho “corretto” un cartello che parlava di _utilizzazione dell'aula_ universitaria  cambiando _utilizzazione_ in _utilizzazionamento_...). Ciononostante potrebbe esserci del vero in quanto sostenuto da CasaMich.

Comment: @DaG voglio dire: a mio parere le parole vengono spesso allungate per dare loro più lustro. Difficile che _spaventoso_ e _spaventevole_ si trovino in contesti in cui si ha questa necessità, e quindi potrebbe avere il sopravvento il fattore della “praticità fonetica” ipotizzato da CasaMich.

Comment: Sì, grazie, @WalterTross, siamo d'accordo sul maggior prestigio percepito delle parole allungate. A mia volta dicevo solo che essere più lunga e meno facilmente pronunciabile non solo non è di per sé un fattore che sfavorisca una parola, ma anzi – nelle opportune circostanze – ne vengono coniate di proposito, di parole così.

Answer (score 2):

Oltre ad essere `spaventevole` un termine più arcaico ed altisonante, `spaventoso` vuol dire anche "che si spaventa facilmente", "molto soggetto ad aver paura", mentre `spaventevole` significa esclusivamente "che incute spavento".

Nota inoltre che sono entrambi usati in modo figurato come sinonimo di `enorme`, `ingente` e simili. Per esempio

> Le azioni della sua società hanno avuto un incremento spaventoso

In questo caso l'incremento delle azioni non è certo materia di spavento, il termine si pone con il significato di `vertiginoso`, anche con connotazione positiva. Si tende probabilmente ad identificare un generale trasalimento che si può provocare con uno spavento, anche se non è il caso.

Comment: Direi che l'uso di spaventoso come sinonimo di pauroso o fifone non è più presente nell'italiano corrente. Inoltre non mi pare che spaventoso sia più arcaico o altisonante di spaventevole, mi sembra piuttosto vero il contrario.

Comment: Ho sbagliato a scrivere, intendevo il contrario. Corretto. Quando faccio un sacco di modifiche al mio post originale, finisco per dimenticarmi di raccordare due paragrafi separati con conseguenze disdicevoli. Di solito rileggo tutto, ma ogni tanto mi sfugge qualcosa :)

Comment: Il secondo senso di _spaventoso_ viene riportato dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spaventoso/) come "antico e raro", mentre il [Sabatini Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/spaventoso.shtml), lo [Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/spaventoso.php) e il [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=spaventoso) non lo riportano neanche. La parola della quale i due sensi coesistono quasi alla pari è _pauroso_.